# Only allow the post author and admin to comment on a post

Tags: comments

I've searched the interweb and stackexchange high and low and found nothing on how to restrict comment submissions to 1. the post author and 2. the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your theme is set up, [`comments_open`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_open) might be the filter you want. (in functions.php)

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'block_comments_for_others', 10, 2 );
function block_comments_for_others( $is_open, $post_id ) {

    $is_open = false;
    $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );

    if ( get_current_user_id() == $post_author_id || current_user_can('administrator') )
        $is_open = true;

    return $is_open;
}
```

Or possibly something like this right in your theme where you display comments:

```
if ( get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) || current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    comments_template(); 
} else {
    echo "No commenting for you";
}
```

Comment: Works very well.